# In bash, what's the best way for a script to reference the path of another script?

Tags: bash

`scripts/a.sh` calls `scripts/b.sh` through `source` or through `sh`.

But I cannot be sure that the working directory will be `scripts` or the parent of `scripts` or something else.

What is the best practice for  referencing `b.sh`? I can find the directory of the current script, then `cd` to that directory, and then simply call `./b.sh`. But that  seems like a lot of code to put into every script that calls another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a `cd`, cause `source` or command take a full path. Just get the dir name of the full path of your script and run the script from there.

From [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html):

> 0
>   ($0) Expands to the name of the shell or shell script. ....

From [man readlink](https://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink):

> -f, --canonicalize
>   canonicalize by following every symlink in every component of the given name recursively; ...

From [man dirname](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname):

> dirname - strip non-directory suffix from file name

Altogether:

```
. "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"/b.sh
```

I've seen some bash scripts that start with something similar to:

```
DIR=$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")
cd "$DIR"
```

So the current working directory in a script stays the same, even if user runs it from another directory.

@edit

Like @GordonDavisson suggested in comments, we can also add your dir to PATH:

```
export PATH="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")":"$PATH"
```

Then running:

```
. a.sh
```

will search for `a.sh` script through inside directories listed in PATH variable, which it will find in the first dir.

Comment: Are you  that we  reference b.sh based on the directory of the invoking script, a.sh. OK, I can do that, but it seems complicated. I'd prefer if a.sh could just invoke something as simple as  ./b.sh (recognizing that ./b.sh actually works from the PWD, so that is not the solution ). In Java or Python, we set the JAVA_PATH or PYTHONPATH for this purpose

Comment: `$0` is not reliable for this, because if the script's directory is in `$PATH` and the script is run by just its name, `$0` will be just the script name (no directory). If you're using bash, `$BASH_SOURCE` is better. See [BashFAQ #28: How do I determine the location of my script? I want to read some config files from the same place.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) Also, I don't recommend using `cd` in scripts, since that'll invalidate any relative paths passed as arguments, etc.

Comment: @JoshuaFox I find `"$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"/...` pretty simple, normal and common. I think maybe you are more interested in PATH variable, like @GordonDavisson suggests.